# Using string data type in strlwr()

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a problem when I use `string` as data type in `strlwr` for example:

```
string a;
cout << "Enter a":; 
cin >> a;
strlwr(a);
```

Suddenly I get an error!

"[Error] C:\Users\PC\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled7.cpp:7: E2285 Could not find a match for '_lstrlwr(string)' in function main()"

Who can solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please provide the error so that we can further assist you?

Comment: @BunThaiDeng `std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), a.begin(), ::tolower);`  That solves your problem.  Now I guess it's up to you whether you want to understand what this does.  I will give you the benefit of the doubt that you do want to learn C++ and use best practices.

Comment: This is my error  "[Error] C:\Users\PC\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled7.cpp:7: E2285 Could not find a match for '_lstrlwr(string)' in function main()"

Answer (score 3):

The first problem in your code, is that you have one extra double qoutes `"`

```
    string a;
cout<<"Enter a":"; cin>>a;
//            ^ this is extra
strlwr(a);
```

The correct way to write this code is

```
string a;
cout << "Enter a :";
cin >> a;
strlwr(a);
```

with good use of white spaces that help you spot this kind of errors, but in this particular case the syntax highlighting is very helpful.

Also, you can't pass a `std::string` to `strlwr()` it does not expect a string but a `char *` pointer, or more precisely a [c](/questions/tagged/c) string.

This is not a standard function and if you care for portability, you must use standard functions/methods.

To do it directly on the `string` object, you can try like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int
main(void)
{
    std::string example = "ExAmPle";
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < example.size() ; ++i)
    {
        char character = tolower(example[i]);
        example[i] = character;
    }
    std::cout << example;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i use this strlwr(a.c_str()); it still appears the same error !!

Comment: There is one problem, you never say what is the error!

Comment: Sorry about that !! it appears like this "[Error] C:\Users\PC\Documents\C-Free\Temp\Untitled7.cpp:7: E2285 Could not find a match for '_lstrlwr(string)' in function main()"

Comment: @BunThaiDeng Do not use `strlwr()` it's not a portable function, and it's intended for [tag:c] strings, so you should probably avoid it in c++. Please see my sample code using `tolower()` instead.

Comment: Look up `std::transform`.

Comment: yeah!! i've tried these both,strlwr and tolower, but it always appears the the error i showed you. If i use char * or char , i won't get this error !!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: there is an answer here on SO that uses it, but I thought it might be too complicated for a new c++ programmer.

Comment: @BunThaiDeng you can't pass a `std::string` to the `tolower()` function neither. It expects a `char` so you can pass only a single character at a time, just as I show in my example.

Comment: @iharob `but I thought it might be too complicated for a new c++ programmer.`  Where did the OP state he/she is a new programmer?

Comment: So, The best way is i change string to char data type to use in tolower() or  strlower() ?

Comment: @iharob: I assume `strlwr` requires its argument to be `char *`, while the return value of `std::string::c_str()` is `const char *`. So `strlwr(a.c_str());` won't compile.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right, but I am no c++ expert. It makes sense, so I will edit this answer.

Answer (score 2):

`strlwr` is not a part of C++ library & hence it doesn't work. You can rather use :-

```
for (char &ch:a)
    {
          ch = tolower(ch);
    }
```

Comment: I just did it for fun @iharob

Comment: Your method is better @AnkitAcharya for such a case because a range based for loop is better for cleaner iterations

Comment: @Anwesha What are range based loops are they C++14 or something? I really have never seen that except, in Java! Also, I disagree. If the loop is clearly written and the variables correctly named both are just as clear, actually it's not possible to know over what you are iterating in this code.

Comment: @iharob seems that u rn't updated with even C++11. Range based for loops are same as `for each` loops in Java but in C++ they are more powerful because you can send objects by `reference` here

Comment: @iharob She didn't say that the loop wasn't clearly written, but she mean't that `range based for` needs less code & less updation

Comment: Sorry ... sorry I don't do c++ coding. I just wanted to learn. Thanks for the info. @Anwesha And I did notice that, which makes the code very elegant by the way (*the reference thing*).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to get a linker not able to find _lstrlwr.
I'm on Embarcadero® C++Builder 10 Seattle Version 23.0.20618.2753,
and frequently have such problems, especially after messing with the order of the header files in a newer project.

Turn pre=compiled header files off for a while until the project is a bit more stable. I came here because I also had a missing _lstrlwr, as well other complaints. Turning off PCH resolved all of those kinds of problems.